# LINQ statement with multiple Join is very slow

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq

I have a LINQ statement to an Oracle DB with multiple JOINS that is taking a very long time to process (>30 seconds).  When I view the outputted SQL it looks very strange and contains many subqueries.  I am thinking I need to optimize this statement somehow but I am not quite sure.

```
  var WRs = (from c in db.WR_CONTACT
      join wr in db.WORK_REQUEST on c.WR_NO equals wr.WR_NO
      join z in db.TASKS on wr.WR_NO equals z.WR_NO
      join p in db.PEOPLE on z.RESPONSIBLE_PERSON_NO equals p.PERSON_NO
         where p.USERID == key && (z.WR_TASK_NO == 1 || z.WR_TASK_NO == 2) 
            && wr.WR_CANCEL_DATE == null 
            && wr.ACCOUNTING_CLOSE_DATE == null
      select c);
```

I have also tried the OUTER JOIN approach and that did not significantly improve the performance.  The only thing I can think to do is break this off and create a new SQL view.

Comment: Does it run slow in SQL Developer too? You have indexes on the FKs?

Comment: The outputted LINQ query takes a very long time to run in Oracle

Comment: You have indices on WR_NO,RESPONSIBLE_PERSON_NO, WR_TASK_NO, WR_CANCEL_DATE and ACCOUNTING_CLOSE_DATE?

Comment: well, 30 Seconds when e.g. selecting 10'000'000 records isn't a long time against selecting 1000 records, than it would be a long time. so the 30 seconds is relativ to the amount of data your query fetches. would be interesting which amount of data you get here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up creating a SQL view and linking entity to that view.  Not the best solution but it was the best option for our timeline.